# ArgumentOutOfRangeException for DateTime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I think I have stumbled over a bug in VS2012.

Does anybody see how the following can NOT be a bug?

```
Public ReadOnly Property Email_DateTimeSent(ByVal uIndex As Integer) As DateTime
    Get

        If uIndex < _emails.Count Or uIndex < 0 Then
            Stop'this line is not reached, so the index is valid
        End If

        Return _emails(uIndex).EMail_DateTimeSent

    End Get
End Property
```

The error is "ArgumentOfRangeException: The index may not be negativ and not be smaller than the list."

However, when I hover over the line

```
            Return _emails(uIndex).EMail_DateTimeSent,
```

I see that the value is valid and also not out of range: 
    _emails(uIndex).EMail_DateTimeSent = #7/12/2014 2:19:23 AM#

Does anybody see how this can result in an error??

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if `uIndex` is 5 and `Count` is 6, and what if `uIndex` is 7 and `Count` is 6?

Comment: What is _emails?  It looks like it must be a list of some class that has a property .EMail_DateTimeSent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition to validate the index should look for values that are less than zero, or *greater or equal* to the count:

```
If uIndex >= _emails.Count Or uIndex < 0 Then
```

With the current code, the only way to reach the `Return` statement is to provide an index that is greater or equal to the count, i.e. outside the list (or wait for the debugger stop at the `Stop` statement and then continue execution).